# HP Pavillion HPE

Tags: windows-7, memory, hp-pavilion, readyboost

My computer has 16GB ram. It is very slow when rendering 3D models. The CPU meter shows 100%.
I have been informed from HP that no upgrade to the memory is possible as the mother board will not allow it. I have been informed that windows 7 will only allow 16Gbt. If I up grade to winows 7 professional and use a 16gb flash drive as a readyboost will this speed up my rendering time?

Comment: ReadyBoost can do little in this case, and won't replace more RAM, ever. Also, if you already reached the maximum amount of RAM that your motherboard can support, upgrading to the Professional edition would be pointless since you can't add more memory. What the exact model? What are the technical specifications? Did you upgrade/replace anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who's done 3D modeling before, it can be frustrating. My advice is just to leave it. Go read a book or play a game, and check on it periodically. That's what I do.

I don't know what kind of modeling you're doing, or what program you're in, but if you happen to be in OpenSCAD, you can get a pretty good, quick render by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> instead of <kbd>F6</kbd>.